# Get first and second element of array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

How I get first and second element in this array?

[image]

for example the first "AF" and second "Afghanistan", I need to put the value in html select tag

Comment: What you have tried so far ..?

Comment: echo $arr[235]["AF"];

Comment: unset[YOURARRAY['']];

Comment: i do array_chunk, array_shift, array_values($countries) it return "htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given" unfortunately the keys is not numeric, anyone help?

Comment: Post code, not images. This is not Flickr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code it looks like you actually want the key and the value...

```
<select name="country">
<?php
foreach($countryArray as $code=>$country){
echo "<option value=".$code.">".$country."</option>";
}
</select
```

Comment: I need first and second element and it works, thanks you help my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_slice`:

```
$input_array = array('a'=>'a', 'b'=>'b', 'c'=>'c', 'd', 'e');
$first_two =  array_slice($input_array, 0, 2, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array_slice`

```
$arrays = [
        "" => "Select country",
        "AF" => "Afghanistan",
        "DZ" => "Algerian",
        "AO" => "Angola"
    ];

$first = array_slice($arrays, 0, 1);
$second = array_slice($arrays, 1, 1);
$first_two = array_slice($arrays, 0, 2, true);   
$first_three = array_slice($arrays, 0, 3, true);
```